# porting iPhone app to WP7

Tags: iphone, windows-phone-7

I'm a .net developer. A collegue of mine asked me to port some iPhone apps to WP7 (of course rewriting them from scratch).

I would like to know what can do and don't in WP7 compare to iPhone, just to know what it is possible to port and what don't.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

In terms of high-level concepts, most of the stuff you can do on iPhone you can also do on WP7.  Things like:

- taking photos
- getting the Geo-location
- accessing the microphone
- using the accelerometer
- open a webpage / browser
- make a phone call
- send an SMS
- etc

are all possible on both.  You just go about it in very conceptually and programmatically different ways.

Here's a list of [features](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402551%28VS.92%29.aspx) and [common tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.tasks%28VS.92%29.aspx).

However, Windows Phone and the IOS platform are completely different.  You're looking at:

- Objective C vs XAML + C# (or XNA if you don't like Silverlight)
- Completely different libraries and controls
- Completely different UI models (check out the [UI Design and Interaction Guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff637515%28VS.92%29.aspx))

As someone recently tasked with porting an existing iPhone / Android app to WP7, I can tell you there is absolutely nothing that is the same in this department.  The only salvageable part was the back-end that all three talk to.

Mostly what you spend your time doing is re-designing your UI flow to place nice in the WP7 Panorama / Pages view of the world.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. No my question was probably a little cryptic. Of course Obj-C and C# are totally different languages (luckily :) ), so Panorama and Cococa. I was asking if there was some feature (at user level) with WP7 you cannot implement. For examples launching bing map app from an application as you can do with google maps app on iphone and so on...

Comment: No, most of that is all possible.  You do have to get an API key for Bing maps.  But there's a little map widget in the toolbox you can drag into your XAML in the designer.  I suspect iPhone is probably more restrictive, if anything.  WP7 even supports AM/FM radio, apparently.  If you have specific concerns, you should list them.  Otherwise we're just playing guessing games.  There are a lot of features in both phones.

Comment: Thanks, I will look at feature requests, and in such a suspicius case I will post a question.